# Jumping animation in NavigationStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Apple deprecated NavigationView and requires to use NavigationStack instead. However, I found a problem when using NavigationStack with List and NavigationLink. Here is an example of the code:

```
NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<15) { _ in
                     NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
                         RowItem()
                     }
                }
            }
}
```

When the navigationTitle is large and you tap any element in the List, it takes you to SomeView(). And when you scroll down a little (when the navTitle gets small) and do the same thing, all elements jump down as SwiftUI trying to create a space that large title requires. And when you go back from SomeView(), everything seems fine like nothing jumped. And you can only see that when the transition is performed. NavigationView does not have that strange jumping behaviour.

And what I find strange, if you embed NavigationLink in any stack (VStack, HStack etc), animation gets performed as it meant to be. What is the trick, and what is it that breaks NavigationLink? Is embedding it into any stack a bad practise?

```
VStack {
     NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
         RowItem()
     }
}
```

Comment: In addition to `NavigationView`, you also shouldn't be using that `NavigationLink` initialiser that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NavigationStack you need to use the form NavigationLink(value: ) as that other one is deprecated in this context so like this..

```
NavigationStack {
 List {
  ForEach(0..<15) { _ in
   NavigationLink(value: "Row") {
     RowItem()
   }
  }
 }
 .navigationTitle("Title One")
 .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
   SomeView()
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I googled more information on that, and it seems that my method is not deprecated and still valid to use as NavigationLink got completely new API. I was also having hard times trying to implement your method to navigate to another view, and the problem was the NavigationStack in the view that was pushed onto the screen. Wondering why my way works fine with NavigationStack in a new view. Any ideas?

Comment: True it still works but the documentation only mentions using adding a navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier inside the stack’s view hierarchy which suggests this is best practice. I couldn't replicate your issue (missing what the SomeView and RowItem look like) so wondered if using the modifier approach removed the issue ?

Comment: navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier only created a problem lol. But as I said, the problem was a NavigationStack in SomeView. By removing it, I solved the issue. I didn't notice any difference using both methods. But the jumping List item behavior persisted. And again, such behavior was eliminated by embedding NavigationLink into VStack. To have an idea of what I am talking about, simply populate enough items to beable to scroll down, then tap any of them and you will see the weird animation on background. I also see it in some tutorial videos and no one addresses it